# How to select shape and run macro to fill color?

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I am trying to select a shape and fill this shape with a color in a PowerPoint presentation like that (I put my code on the green button):

```
Sub ChangeInRed()


   If ActiveWindow.Selection.Type = ppSelectionNone Then
        MsgBox "Please selecte a zone !"
   Else
        For Each shp In ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange
          shp.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 0, 0)
        Next shp
   End If


End Sub
```

If I run my code from macros-code, my selected shape changes to red; if I don't have a shape selected, my code displays: "Please select a zone".

All good, but in the edit mode, my button is not active to run this piece of code and I tried that in PRESENTATION mode.

When I try to select a shape in the presentation mode, my slideshow gets to the next page but I don't need that.

I want to select the shape and press the button to change the color to red, or I want to click on the shape and change the color.

If I try the code from the top in macro-code, my shape changes to red, but not in presentation.

My question is: how to select a shape in the presentation mode and change color?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want the shape to change colour during a slide show, copy the macro below to your PowerPoint .pptm (or .ppsm) file and then with the shape selected, go to the PowerPoint ribbon and click **Insert** / **Action** and in the **Mouse Click** tab, click **Run Macro** and make sure the **ChangeShapeColour** macro is selected before clicking **OK**.

[image]

```
Option Explicit

Sub ChangeShapeColour(ByRef oShp As Shape)
  oShp.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 0, 0)
End Sub
```

Comment: Work if i put code for one shape, but if i try to put this on button and when i click him to color shape how cand i do?

Comment: You can't, because you can't select anything in slide show view.